# Cells attached to each other in a UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Why, when I create a CollectionView, and dequeque two cells with different identifier, the latter are attached to each other?
The cells with the same identifier have equal distance between them, instead the cells with different identifier are stuck together.
Here my code:

```
  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    if (section == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (section == 1) {
        return 10;
    }
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell;
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AddCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        UIImageView *cellImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        [cellImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pulsante_trasparente.png"]];
    }

    else if (indexPath.section == 1){
    cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PictureCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *cellImage = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    [cellImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mi.png"]];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Are the PictureCells sticking to each other, or to an AddCell?

Comment: When identifier change, a CollectionViewCell attaches itself to another cell with different identifier. That is, I've 3 cell with AddCell identifier, and 6 cell with PictureCell identifier. When the identifier change, and thus change from AddCell to PictureCell, the last AddCell cell attaches itself to the first PictureCell cell

Comment: Are the two types of cells different sizes?

Answer (score 2):

Implement this method to get space between cells of different sections:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section;
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(Top_Gap, Left_Gap, Buttom_Gap, Right_Gap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the minimum Spacing for cells at a negative value if not do so by going to the `UICollectionView` in your xib and selecting the inspector and customizing the minimum space there. I have a image for you showing what I mean:

[image: CollectionView Inspector]